# Why not see the full picture for my background?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://www.delumine.ch/clients-prives/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<section class="title_bar">

//some code HTML

</section>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.page-id-1662 .title_bar {
    background: url("http://www.delumine.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/delumine-03.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center; }
```

My problem is the background for this section is incomplete sees and does not understand why ...

Can you tell me please what is the reason?
Please open the original image and watch show

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Taking a look at your webpage, your section element doesn't have "background-size: contain;" in it's final computed styles, either you have forgot to update the CSS there or some other rule is overriding it, try adding "background-size: contain !important;" to make sure no other rules override it and also make sure your webpage CSS is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Down load the image on to your computer than find it using a path.

Example from my code:

```
#main_nav {
color: white;
padding: 30 px;
margin: 0px 0px;
height: 200 px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
**background-image: url(../Images/Banner-2.jpg);**
}
```

I would keep all your files in organised folders.

Thanks, adbadb25

Answer (score 0):

May be it is due to margin top in your wp-content/plugins/tabs/css/style.css

```
.tabs-container {
  margin: 50px 0; // Here margin set to 50px...reset it and try
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```